# IntelliJ IDEA: GIT: "CreateProcess failed with error 87: The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I just tried switching from IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5 to 2016.3 and I cannot use git anymore.

The first manifestation of this problem was that my "Version Control: Local Changes" tab was empty, and the message `The String 'Head' does not represent a revision number` appeared at the bottom.  After quite a bit of troubleshooting, I could not find any fix for that.

Then I noticed by accident that in my "Version Control: Console" tab there were some error messages like this:

```
21:48:56.850: [java2] git -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin --progress --prune
CreateProcess failed with error 87: The parameter is incorrect.
```

After quite a bit more troubleshooting, I could not find any solution to this one, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that under `Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> Path to Git executable` my path to git was enclosed in double quotes, which used to work just fine with IDEA 2016.2.5, but apparently the magic is not true anymore with 2016.3, and the path must **not** be enclosed in quotes.